# eclipse is not showing import statements properly in java

Tags: eclipse

I have taken date object like `Date d = new Date();` in eclipse.I did not import anything.But it is compiling successfully. How is it possible

Comment: Could you show some code to the audience, please?

Comment: please show your whole code.

Comment: In groovy it is already imported class. So is it groovy?

Answer (score 2):

Your Eclipse might have ***Save Actions*** enabled.  It is accessible at `Eclipse Menu => Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions => Organize imports (checked)`.

[image: Eclipse::Save Actions::Organize Imports]

Comment: Also import statemens are collapseable, so all import statements can be shown in one line and only the first one is readable.